# Definite integral involving e and ln

Tags: logarithms, definite-integrals

I am supposed to solve a definite integral which involves $\ln$ and $e$. Nowhere in my textbook can I even find examples of how this would be done.

I do know that $\ln(e(x))$ and $e(\ln(x))$ evaluates to $x$, but I don't know how this is supposed to help me with this question.

Determine the possible value of the definite integral $\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(\ln(t))}{t\ \log_{2}(w)}dt$

Comment: Are you sure about the $w$ in the integral ? If it is a constant then you can move it outside the integral. If it is a function of $t$ then please give details.

Comment: Hint: Let $u = \ln t$, then $du = \frac{dt}t$ ...

Comment: @vanna Yes w is a constant.

Comment: @MichaelFrey then take $\log(w)$ out of the integral. You are left with something of the form $u'(v)\cdot v'$. Do you not recognise this?

Comment: @JulienGodawatta Ok. I get the taking out of $log(w)$, but how do you see that I am left with something in the form of $u'(v)\cdot v'$?

Comment: @MichaelFrey By letting $u'(t)=\ln t,\;v(t)=\ln t,\;v'(t)=\dfrac{1}{t}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = ln(t)$.
Then $du = \frac{dt}{t}$.
Let $c = \frac{1}{log_{2}(w)}$

Then $\int_{e}^{e^2} \frac{\ln(\ln(t))}{t\ \log_{2}(w)}dt = c\int_{1}^{2} \ln(u)du = c[u \ln(u) - u]_{1}^{2} = c(2\ln(2) - 1)$